# insert a image into outlook

Tags: javascript, html, email, outlook

my site has a "send" button to send email, I want to send some email(outlook) fill with some existed info from my site.

for example, I want a logo image show in the email body,how can I get that?

here is my html and js:

```
<a id="email"  target="_blank" href="">send email</a>

<script>
$('#mail').click(function() {
    var link = "mailto: some" + "?cc=cc" + "&subject=subject" + "&body = '"+ ??+"'";
    window.location.href = link;
    return false;
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with a "mailto" url. You will need to either generate the email on your server or use JavaScript in IE on the client side (if your site is in the trusted list) to create a message using the Outlook Object Model. An even then, you would need the image file to be locally present to be able to add to the message.